# Кроссбраузерность, центровка на Mac OS в Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Падскажите кроссбраузерный способ как текст внутри блока выровнять по вертикали по центру.

В **первом примере** (с номерками) я для блока задал **line-height** равный его высоте. У меня на Windows во всех браузерах все хорошо, а вот на  Mac OS центровка почему-то нарушается.

```css
.number {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0046bf;
  font-family: "Harmonia Sans Pro Cyr Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="number">01</div>
```

Слева — так должно быть, справа — так в Mac OS в Google Chrome:

[image] [image]

Для кнопки задал разные **padding-top** и **padding-bottom** с учетом размера **line-height**, чтобы в итоге отсуп сверху и снизу был одинаковый. На Windows он у меня и стал одинаковый, но в Mac OS все поехало.

```css
.card__btn {
  display: block;
  width: 310px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(166deg, #336ace 0%, #3972d5 50%, #235abf 50%, #013ca3 100%);
}
```

```html
<a class="card__btn" href="#">
   Хочу купить и растаможить <br> Ford Focus на меня
</a>
```

Слева — так должно быть; справа — так на Mac OS в Google Chrome:

[image] [image]

Comment: Есть неуверенное предположение, что это может быть связано со шрифтом. Вы пробовали менять шрифт на другой ради эксперимента? Например, я сейчас ваш код завернул в сниппеты, и при отсутствии шрифта Harmonia на компьютере используется стандартный шрифт браузера — если вы их попробуете запустить в ваших хроме и сафари, оно ровное или неровное?

Comment: @andreymal, Поставил шрифт Arial, запустил тест для Mac OS, то да, в номерках текст по вертикали выровнялся ровно по центру. Получается это шрифт какой-то некорректный, нужно другой использовать?

Comment: Я не юзал ваших шрифтов и не могу отвечать точно, но возможно что так

Comment: Если к сайту подключен шрифт в нескольких разных форматах, то возможно какой-то один из форматов (который используется в маке) оказался кривой, а остальные (один из которых используется в винде) некривые, но это я наугад предполагаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать отцентровать текст с помощью `display: flex`, `justify-content: center` и `align-items: center`

```css
.card__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 310px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(166deg, #336ace 0%, #3972d5 50%, #235abf 50%, #013ca3 100%);
}
```

```html
<a class="card__btn" href="#">
   Хочу купить и растаможить <br> Ford Focus на меня
</a>
```